# Comparing signatures in Ink Serialized Format

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-vista, tablet-pc

I have a load of signatures I wish to compare (all in ISF - ink serialized format).

How to compare these signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I ended up using a mperfect idea and analysing the signatures using speed, time, distance and created an algorythm which works.